# Amazon SQS without BOTO

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-sqs

I have a requirement to access Amazon SQS service. I am not allowed to use BOTO as it is a 
restricted environment.I am new to Python.

Any suggestions??

Comment: So you can only use the standard Python runtime libraries, but not any other third-party libraries?

Comment: I can only use standard libs. Its python 2.3.4

Comment: Wow, Python 2.3.4 is 10 years behind current Python releases. I recommend that you write your own mini boto-like library and get some help by looking at how boto itself constructs Amazon REST api calls, signs requests, and deconstructs responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply do what Boto does internally: construct the API request to [AWS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/MakingRequests_MakingQueryRequestsArticle.html). It is a bit of work, but using the standard library (something like [urllib2](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html)) you can get the same information that Boto returns (with some additional parsing).

Comment: Thanks for the links. Exactly what I was looking for. But its a pain to reinvent the wheel.